# Meniscus of water after breaking the capillary

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension, capillary-action

Let us take the capillary dipped in water and we let the water climb normally till its maximum height. Now we break the capillary (assume clean cleavage so there aren't any rough surfaces produced) at some point so that there is some water present above the point.

Question is what will happen to the waterline shape at the point where we broke the meniscus. I thought that since the point where we broke, is now subject to atmospheric pressure, a similar meniscus as present at the top of the capillary will form at the bottom.

But the actual answer given is that nothing will happen to the water line shape, i.e. waterline shape will be flat at the bottom. So I seek why this is such the case. Please help, every help is massive appreciation